# How do I ask user to input numbers to then store in text file?

Tags: python, text, input, numbers, average

I need to have the user input a certain amount of numbers (5) and have them stored in a text file. 
I also need to find the average of those numbers. Would I use the sum function for that and then divide by 5?

This is for python and I use the IDLE 3.4 version on OS X.

```
lst = list() #creates a list to later store nubers in

def addtolist():  #creates a function for adding numbers to the list
  def listcount():  #
        try:
              lst.append(int(input("Enter a number:")))
        except ValueError:
              print("That was not a number")
        print(lst)
  listcount()

  yes = ["yes", "y"]
  no = ["no", "n"]
  yup = ["yes", "y"]
  nah = ["no", "n"]

  enteragain = input("Enter another number? yes/no")
  if enteragain in yes:
        print("Ok")
  elif enteragain in no:
        print("We'll try again")
        addtolist()

  runagain = input("Are those the numbers you wanted to enter?")
  if runagain in yes:
        print("Ok")
  elif runagain in no:
        print("We'll try again")
        addtolist()

addtolist()
```

Comment: Write some code first. Your problem is not hard at all and the best part is you already know the solution.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! All that has been posted is a program description. However, we need you to [ask a question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). We can't be sure what you want from us. Please [edit] your post to include a valid question that we can answer. Reminder: make sure you know [what is on-topic here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), asking us to write the program for you and suggestions are off-topic.

Comment: @KevinGuan I think we can be pretty sure what they want from us...

Comment: @jonrsharpe That's not the important part :P. Because I'm using [*AutoReviewComments*](http://stackapps.com/questions/2116/autoreviewcomments-pro-forma-comments-for-se), and seems like this is the right one for this post in the comments list.

Comment: *"Would I use the sum function for that and then divide by 5?"* - have you tried that? What happened? Is the problem that you aren't sure how to calculate averages, how to implement that in Python, that you've tried to implement it but it doesn't work, ...?

Comment: I'm sorry for any misunderstanding since I'm still a little confused about how to use all this. 
I edited the file and added in the code that I have so far.

Comment: So what's the **problem** with the code you have? A [mcve] would be much more useful.

Comment: I don't know how to create a text file instead of a list and also I can't empty the list that I created. So when I input 'no' for the "Are those the numbers you wanted to enter?" instead of emptying the list it adds more numbers to it.

Comment: http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/files/reading-and-writing-files-in-python

Answer (score 0):

I fiddled a little with it and instead of storing the list as a text file I decided to keep it in list form. Here is what I came up with at the end:

```
lst = list()
def addtolist():  #creates a function for adding numbers to the list
  def listcount():  #
        try:
              lst.append(int(input("Enter a number: ")))
        except ValueError:
              print("That was not a number")
              addtolist()
        print(lst)
  listcount()

  yes = ["yes", "y"]
  no = ["no", "n"]

  def playagain():
        enteragain = input("Enter another number? yes/no?... ")
        if enteragain in no:
              print("Ok!\n Calculating average.../n")
        elif enteragain in yes:
              print("Ok then!")
              addtolist()
        else:
              print("Please type either yes or no")
              playagain()
  playagain()

addtolist()

total = sum(lst)
numbers = len(lst)
average = total/numbers

print("The average of", lst, "is", average)
```